# How to trigger an event when Storyboard properties change in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml

I have a storyboard animation of a control scaling up and down and I want to get a propertychanged callback when the scale value changes in the storyboard.

```
<Storyboard x:Name="ScaleLoop" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ScalingObject" EnableDependentAnimation="True">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

the animation above is simple but in the future I plan to animate a more complex one.

```
<Canvas x:Name="ScalingObject">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleY="1"/>
     </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
```

this is the callback that I am using:

```
long handle = this.ScalingObject.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(Canvas.RenderTransformProperty, new DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(this.ChangeState));
```

but this only gets fired once.

Is this is best way to do this?

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
B

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `Canvas.RenderTransformProperty` can not fire the event.

You should be able to use the [`CompositeTransform.ScaleYProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.CompositeTransform#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_CompositeTransform_ScaleYProperty) to set to the [`RegisterPropertyChangedCallback`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject#Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyObject_RegisterPropertyChangedCallback_Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyProperty_Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyPropertyChangedCallback_) method. When the value of the `CompositeTransform.ScaleYProperty` is changed, the ChangeState event will be fired.

For example:

```
var compositeTransform = (CompositeTransform)ScalingObject.RenderTransform;
long handle = compositeTransform.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(CompositeTransform.ScaleYProperty, new DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(this.ChangeState));
```

Comment: @BUD Does the answer can solve you issue? If not, please tell more detail about this.